# Dijkstra's algorithm for longest path

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

**EDIT 2: This might be too late, but I figured out the problem, it was me. I misunderstood the project, it asked for the largest bandwidth path not the longest path. which is different but I didn't know until now. So basically in any bandwidth path problem (whether largest or smallest), the weights are not accumulated, the path value is determined by the smallest weight in the path. Think of it as a path of pipes and the water flow is determined by the thinest pipe along the path.**

**EDIT 1: I fixed the PQ issue, but still not working.**

It is an assignment (I admit), but I may fail the whole course if I don't submit it. We are supposed to modify Dijkstra's algorithm to calculate the longest SIMPLE path instead of the shortest path. I couldn't figure out a solution. I searched the Internet and found [this](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs2321/www/newLectures/30_More_Dijkstra.htm) (It is even the same problem).

But when I run it, it produces incorrect values. Is there any thing I'm missing ? Why even doesn't it sum the weight with the predecessor ? Why use min ?

Info about the graph:
 1. We generate the graph randomly such that each node is connected to
    about 25% of the other nodes.
 2. Weights are positive.
 3. There are 25 nodes in the graph.

The question says "Routing Algorithm is the algorithm of finding maximum bandwidth path in a graph. It is based on modification of Dijkstra’s algorithm using a Max-Heap structure". Is there any trick in it that may help ?

```
public class MaxDijkstra {
    Graph graph;
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue;

    public MaxDijkstra(Graph graph, Node s){
        this.graph = graph;
        s.addAttribute("ui.class", "start");
        queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
                if(Utils.getNodeBW(n1) == Utils.getNodeBW(n2)){
                    return 0;
                }else if(Utils.getNodeBW(n1) < Utils.getNodeBW(n2)){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });

        // init
        for(Node n : graph){
            Utils.setNodeBW(n, 0);
        }
        Utils.setNodeBW(s, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

        // add to Q
        for(Node n : graph){
            queue.add(n);
        }

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            Node u = queue.remove();
            Iterator<Node> iterator = u.getNeighborNodeIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Node v = iterator.next();
                float min = Float.min(Utils.getNodeBW(u), Utils.getEdgeBW(u.getEdgeBetween(v)));
                if(min > Utils.getNodeBW(v)){
                    Utils.setNodeBW(v, min);
                    Utils.setPreOfNode(v, u);
                }
            }

            // validate PQ
            // I know it is not good, just for debuggin now
            // I will implemnt my own PQ later
            List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while(!queue.isEmpty()){
                Node w = queue.remove();
                list.add(w);
            }
            for(Node w : list){
                queue.add(w);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        for(Node n : graph){
            System.out.println("N="+n.getId()+" D="+Utils.getNodeBW(n)+" pre="+ (Utils.getPreOfNode(n) == null ? "NIL" : Utils.getPreOfNode(n).getId()) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Just to colourise the path
     * @param target 
     */
    public void backtrack(Node target){
        target.addAttribute("ui.class", "end");
        Node currunt = target;
        Node pre = Utils.getPreOfNode(currunt);
        while(pre != null){
            currunt.getEdgeBetween(pre).addAttribute("ui.class", "route");
            currunt = pre;
            pre = Utils.getPreOfNode(currunt);
        }
    }
```

Sample output:
[image: Not the highest bandwidth]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Using the algorithm on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Algorithm, change step 3 to always take the largest distance value instead of the smallest.

Comment: longest path problem is NP-hard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Weighted_directed_acyclic_graphs

Comment: so are there restrictions on the graph?

Comment: @JonathanM what about positive weight cycles?

Comment: How large will the graph be ~ (no. of nodes)?

Comment: btw. path generally means simple path in graph theory and longest simple path problem is NP-hard, see above

Comment: @yassin the graph is 25 nodes. such that each node is connected to about 25% of the other nodes (not exactly 25%). weights are positive.

Comment: @yassin I udpdated the original question, may you have a look ?

Comment: @Kh5 ok, this is not the longest path problem, but maximum bandwidth. So you are searching for paths with the weakest link as good as possible.

Comment: @yassin Diagram of any telephone network shows a graph whose vertices represent switches centers, and whose edges represent communication lines between two centers. The network lines have bandwidth and routing the phone call is always done via the highest bandwidth. In this project, you are about designing an algorithm that finds the maximum bandwidth of a path between any two switches centers. Routing Algorithm is the algorithm of finding maximum bandwidth path in a graph. It is based on modification of Dijkstra’s algorithm using a Heap structure.

Comment: @Kh5 I don't see why the pseudocode you linked would not work. Maybe check your implementation carefully?

Comment: Are you supposed to write code or pseudocode? You show you've found some online resource, and you say you "run it", but you don't show what you're running exactly. How are we supposed to help you if you don't show your implementation? See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @PJvG Sorry. I've add the Java code as well as a sample output.

Comment: @yassin I checked it again and again. but no luck. I've add the Java code as well as a sample output.

Comment: @Kh5 Why do you insert every node into the queue in the beginning? Only insert the start node!

Comment: @yassin it says in the link "Initialize priority queue Q of  vertices using BW as key."

Comment: @Kh5 Yes nvm. You totally have to rethink that code. The problem is: you are changing the values that get compared of elements already in the priority queue, but that's not how priority queues work. You are not allowed to alter the elements in there, the priority queue will not resort them on each change.

Comment: @Kh5 second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267172/which-datatype-to-use-as-queue-in-dijkstras-algorithm

Comment: In your post, what do you mean by "simple" when you say you want the longest simple path?

Comment: @JonathanM Simple path is a path where all the nodes are distinct. i.e. no duplicated nodes.

Comment: @yassin I worked around it by removing all the nodes in the PQ and then re insert them. not good just for debugging. But it is still not working.

Comment: @Kh5 also, I see you say you've found a work-around to your problem. Perhaps you should consider posting your work-around as an answer so that it might help other people facing the same or similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the longest simple path. This problem is NP-hard. In fact, there's no known polynomial solution to it.

If the graph is relatively small, you can use dynamic programming to get an `O(2^n * poly(n))` solution, which is feasible for n ~ 20-30 (the state is mask of visited vertices and the last vertex. A transition is adding one vertex if it's possible).

If the graph is large, you can use different heuristics and approximations combined with local optimization techniques to get a good (but not necessarily an optimal) solution.

Comment: As the question asks for a modification of Dijkstra: the exponential solution could probably be implemented through Dijsktras, by inserting path length and bitmask into the priority queue.

Comment: @yassin I wouldn't call it a modification. It looks like a completely different algorithm to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying all weights by -1 to make all of the weights negative.  Then you can use the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.  The Floyd-Warshall algorithm works with negative weights in a graph that doesn't have a cycle.  So, use Floyd-Warshall to find the smallest path, which when multiplied by -1, will be your maximum path in the original graph.

Comment: But we are supposed to modify Dijkstra's algorithm. Can we use the -1 trick with it (with some modification) ?

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't read your original question carefully.  Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work with negative weights.  My idea will only work with an algorithm that works with negative weights, like Floyd-Warshall.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter elements already in the priority queue. 
Normally for Dijkstra you need a `decrease key` function, but the one from the library doesn't support that, so you can just reinsert nodes multiple times into the pq with different BW values. Something like this (regard this as pseudocode :))

```
    PriorityQueue<pair<Node, int>> queue;

    public MaxDijkstra(Graph graph, Node s){

        queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<pair<Node, int>>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(pair<Node, int> n1, pair<Node, int> n2) {
                return n1.second > n2.second;
            }
        });

        // init
        for(Node n : graph){
            Utils.setNodeBW(n, 0);
        }
        Utils.setNodeBW(s, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // add to Q
        for(Node n : graph){
            queue.add({n, n.getNodeBW()});
        }

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            pair<Node, int> u = queue.remove();
            if (u.second < u.first.getNodeBW()) continue; //important - skip if you already saw better value
            Iterator<Node> iterator = u.getNeighborNodeIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Node v = iterator.next();
                int min = Integer.min(Utils.getNodeBW(u), Utils.getEdgeBW(u.getEdgeBetween(v)));
                if(min > Utils.getNodeBW(v)){
                    Utils.setNodeBW(v, min);
                    queue.insert({v, min});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know. I have worked around it, not good I know, just for debugging. But that sill not helping fixing the problem.

Comment: @Kh5 Hmm, my only idea right now is that `getEdgeBW` doesn't work correctly.